# python dictionary in dictionary changing value

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

```
teams = ['Argentina', 'Australia', 'Belgium', 'Brazil', 'Colombia', 'Costa Rica', 'Croatia', 'Denmark', 'Egypt', 'England', 'France', 'Germany', 'Iceland', 'Iran', 'Japan', 'Mexico', 'Morocco', 'Nigeria', 'Panama', 'Peru', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Russia', 'Saudi Arabia', 'Senegal', 'Serbia', 'South Korea', 'Spain', 'Sweden', 'Switzerland', 'Tunisia', 'Uruguay']

wins = {"wins" : 0}


combined_data = dict.fromkeys(teams, wins)

combined_data["Russia"]['wins'] +=1

print(combined_data["Belgium"]['wins'])
```

should print 0 but all 'wins' go up by 1 and printout 1

I also tried 'wins' with 32 keys, but not working.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wins` dictionary is shared across *all* keys inside the `combined_data` dictionary.

To resolve this issue, use a dictionary comprehension instead:

```py
combined_data = {team: {"wins" : 0} for team in teams}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not creating a new dictionary for each country, it's putting a reference to *the exact same dictionary* in each key's value. You can see this by running `id()` on two separate keys of the dataframe:

```py
id(combined_data['Argentina'])   # 5077746752
id(combined_data['Sweden'])   # 5077746752
```

To do what you mean to do, you should use something like a dictionary expression:

```py
combined_data = {team: {"wins" : 0} for team in teams}
```

Comment: thank you so much! i will try id next time..

Comment: @apfhddnwls, FYI, the same thing will happen with lists, or any mutable data type. This is the explanation for lots of weird behaviour.